# Format json array to chart input

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, charts

Hi i am getting json array as response of ajax request:

```
{"chart":{"2016-03-08":"1","2016-03-07":"4","2016-03-06":0,"2016-03-05"
:0,"2016-03-04":0,"2016-03-03":"145","2016-03-02":0}}
```

Now i want to prepare a chart by giving these values to chart input as below: ( i want output like this from above array )

```
                              data: [{
                                    y: '2016-03-07',
                                    a: 100
                                    }, {
                                        y: '2016-03-08',
                                        a: 75
                                    }, {
                                        y: '2016-03-06',
                                        a: 50
                                    }, {
                                        y: '2016-03-05',
                                        a: 75
                                    }, {
                                        y: '2016-03-09',
                                        a: 50
                                    }, {
                                        y: '2016-03-03',
                                        a: 75
                                    }, {
                                        y: '2016-03-02',
                                        a: 180
                                    }
                                ],
```

I have tried :

```
var chart_params = {};
for (var key in data_chart) {
     let value = data_chart[key];
     chart_params = '{ y:'+ key+ ', a: '+value+' }';
}
console.log(chart_params);
```

but it is not giving output as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data = {"chart":{"2016-03-08":"1","2016-03-07":"4","2016-03-06":0,"2016-03-05" :0,"2016-03-04":0,"2016-03-03":"145","2016-03-02":0}}

var chart_params = [];
data_chart = data.chart;
 for (var key in data_chart) {
      var value = data_chart[key];
      chart_params.push({ y: key, a:value});
}
 console.log(chart_params);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hb8qd1p8/1/

Comment: @dreamstrue you can mark as answered if it solved your problem

Comment: @dreamstrue , If it worked for you then Why *"cant upvote"* !

Comment: i am new user and Min 15 reputation required. :( if you up-vote our que thn i can get... may be

Comment: @madalinivascu m new.. how to mark answered as it got solved?

Answer (score 1):

**@madalin's** answer is the correct fix for your issue, though another option to accomplish what you want is to use `map`:-

```js
var data = {"chart":{"2016-03-08":"1","2016-03-07":"4","2016-03-06":0,"2016-03-05":0,"2016-03-04":0,"2016-03-03":"145","2016-03-02":0}};

var array = Object.keys(data.chart).map(function (key) {
  return { y: key, a: data.chart[key] }; 
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(array, null, 4));
```

Comment: it got solved. Thank you so much for your answer.. i will up-vote once i will have 15 repo :)